# how to define a string variable with space in variable name in GAMS with $set

Tags: gams-math

I would like to define a string variable in GAMS to call a server. Here is the syntax:

```
$set SERVER SERVER=ASERVER
```

The problem is that there is a space in the server name, so that the actual syntax is

```
$set SERVER SERVER=A SERVER
```

Then errors are reported like this "***Error Unknow option "Server"***". How should I handle a string variable with space in variable name? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with quotes:

```
$set SERVER 'SERVER=A SERVER'
```

Edit: Another example how to use `$call` with an argument containing spaces (note that this is for Windows only, on Unix you would have to handle the spaces and quotes differently):

```
$echo $log %x% > log.gms

$call 'gams log.gms --x="With Space" lo=%gams.lo%'
```

Comment: Thanks Lutz, it does not work me. When I set directory, there is a space within "New Folder", which is included within \**\.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you comment. Would be good, if you could provide another example showing what is not working for you.

Comment: I didn't make it clear. The entire model is defined in multiple gams files. I tried to define string variables in the "run" file, and pass to their corresponding files via "--". The space here causes problems. I also define directory in this way with space in "New Folder", but it works without single quote. I hope it can make this post more clear

Comment: Not sure, if I got it right, but I extended my answer (you do not get nice code formatting here in the comments).